# Git push from local server to Git and then from Git to Demo server

Tags: git, github

May be this is duplicate question but , I am new to git and can't find a way to do it.

What i am trying is,

I have project in my local server which is clone of a repo in git and also have same repo clone in my demo server which is  in EC2 server.

Now what i want is if i update anything from my local system to git , it will automatically send that updated files from git to demo server.

Please check the attached image , It will show How i want code to be flow in system.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [GitHub Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

From [Creating Webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-webhooks)

> Every GitHub repository has the option to communicate with a web server whenever the repository is pushed to. These webhooks can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror, or even deploy to your production server.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with EC2, I have worked in this way:

1.- push the changes to the remote repo

```
git push -u origin
```

2.- From EC2, pull the changes:

```
git pull
```

Note that I have SSH permission to the EC2 instance. So, I treat the ec2 instance as a local repository, except that I make no changes over it.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually, it will automatically send updated to demo server when ever any one push files to git.